# What's the right method to divide and integrate a PHP script inside another one?

Tags: php, html

I just started coding PHP, I know how to include PHP however I encountered difficulties in this case. 
I have a LAMP server, in the root folder I installed my own framework as below (folders are in capital letters).

```
index.php

page.php

INCLUDES

 - classes.php 
 - skins.php
 - flow_init.php
 - flow_head.php
 - flow_body.php

SOURCES

 - page1.php 
 - page2.php

 ...

THEME_HTML

 - wrapper.html

   VIEWS

     - page1.html  

     - page2.html

       ...
```

`wrapper.html` is created into `index.php`

```
<?php // index.php
$skin = new skin('wrapper');
echo $skin->make();
```

This is my `skins.php` file

```
<?php // INCLUDES/skins.php
class skin {
    var $filename;

    public function __construct($filename) {
        $this->filename = $filename;
    }

    public function mk($filename) {
        $this->filename = $filename;
        return $this->make();
    }

    public function make() {
        global $CONF;
        $file = sprintf('./'.$CONF['theme_path'].'/'.$CONF['theme_name'].'/html/%s.html', $this->filename);
        $fh_skin = fopen($file, 'r');
        $skin = @fread($fh_skin, filesize($file));
        fclose($fh_skin);

        return $this->parse($skin);
    }

    private function parse($skin) {
        global $TMPL, $LNG;

        $skin = preg_replace_callback('/{\$lng->(.+?)}/i', create_function('$matches', 'global $LNG; return $LNG[$matches[1]];'), $skin);
        $skin = preg_replace_callback('/{\$([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)}/', create_function('$matches', 'global $TMPL; return (isset($TMPL[$matches[1]])?$TMPL[$matches[1]]:"");'), $skin);

        return $skin;
    }
}
?>
```

Each page of `VIEWS` is created inside `SOURCES` and `page.php` echo it.

---

**Script to integrate**

Everything works fine, but now I need to integrate this script between the wrapper (where the head tag is) and one view (where the content is)

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('admin/plugins/flow-flow/ff-injector.php');
$injector = new FFInjector();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-US">
<head><?php echo $injector->head(true,true); ?>
</head>
<body>

    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 300px;vertical-align: top">
                <?php
                    $stream_id = isset($_REQUEST['stream']) ? $_REQUEST['stream'] : 1;
                    $injector->stream($stream_id);
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

For the purpose I tried to create some templates:

```
<?PHP // index.php
$TMPL['flow_init'] = include './includes/flow_init.php';
$TMPL['flow_head'] = include './includes/flow_head.php';

<?PHP // SOURCES/page1.php
$TMPL['flow_body'] = include './includes/flow_body.php';
```

Where my included files are set as below

```
<?PHP // flow_init.php
session_start();
require_once('admin/plugins/flow-flow/ff-injector.php');
$injector = new FFInjector();
?>

<?PHP // flow_head.php
echo $injector->head(true,true); 
?>

<?PHP // flow_body.php
$stream_id = isset($_REQUEST['stream']) ? $_REQUEST['stream'] : 1;
$injector->stream($stream_id);
?>
```

---

**What I would expect to achieve**

I tried to include `flow_init` and `flow_head` on my wrapper, like this:

```
// THEME_HTML/wrapper.html
{$flow_init}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {$flow_head}
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content" class="wrapper">
        {$content}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And `flow_body` into my content

```
// THEME_HTML/VIEWS/page1.html
<div class="row-body{$content_class}">
    <div class="body-content">
        <div class="nine columns" id="main-content">
            {$flow_body}
        </div>
        <div class="three columns">
            {$sidebar}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The results is a blank page, however if I include all the 3 templates together in the `index.php` it works, so I think it's not a source path problem.

What's the right method to divide a PHP script and make it executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn PSR-4 autoloading and how to use Composer if you want to start including files within files.  This will make it much easier than having to use require_once everywhere you wish to have a file included.

If you're talking about view templating, Don't Reinvent The Wheel, unless you want to learn more about wheels.  The two best templating engines that I've used are Laravel's Blade and Symfony's Twig.  You can also try out the League of PHP Developer's templating engine, which only uses raw PHP.

Comment: So basically I need to insert inside my `classes.php` a new `class` with some `public function`, right? I can't use another framework, it's really to hard at this point.

Comment: Look up composer and PSR-4.  Steps are: Install composer.  Modify composer.json file to use PSR-4 lookup to where all your classes are.  Add the "use MyFolder\MyClass" to each class you want to use.  

You might try setting up a PHPFiddle to demonstrate your code as it's hard to know what went wrong without seeing it live.